# Would header statement work in inner code?

Tags: php

Please see code below:

```
  <?php



  require_once("initvars.php");
  require_once("config.php");

    if( !$auth->id ){
 //NOT logged in
 header("location: index.php"); die();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that you the included files haven't sent any output, yes, that should work.

Note, however, that you really should provide a full URL (`Location: http://example.com/index.php`) to `header`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as long as you have not `echo`'d or produced any output in general.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the contents of the included files. It should work provided the files do not send out any headers. Also see this function [`http_redirect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-redirect.php).